# Find the perpendicular distance between 2 lines

Tags: trigonometry, vector-analysis, intersection-theory

I'm trying to find an equation $d(x,y)$ that defines the distance between a line with slope $1/0.4$ (let's call it $L_1$) and a line with slope $1/2.25$ (let's call it $L_2$). The distance equation must be perpendicular to line $L_1$ but that's the only restriction. The two lines intersect at the point $(x,y) = (762,0)$. Any help would be appreciated, I'm not too sure how to approach this.

Thanks,

Felix

Comment: Since the lines intersect, the distance between them is $0$ by usual definitions of the distance between two lines. Are you trying to find the distance from an arbitrary point on $L_1$ to $L_2$? If so, just parameterize $L_1$ and use the standard point-line distance formula on that.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to find an equation that would give the distance between the 2 lines at any point other than the point of intersection. With the only caveat being that the distance must be perpendicular to L1. I'm not sure if that makes any sense.

Comment: It does. What I wrote in my previous comment is one way to obtain an expression for this distance.

Comment: Ok I understand how to use the point-line formula but I'm just not sure I follow how to extend it so it can be applied to another line?

Comment: You don’t need to apply it to another line. You apply it to an arbitrary point on the other line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a point $(x_0, y_0)$ on $L_1$. The line perpendicular to $L_1$ has slope $=-0.4$. Therefore the equation of the perpendicular line passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by:

$$\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0} = -0.4$$

Let's call the line described above as $L_3$.

Now if we calculate the intersection of $L_3$ and $L_2$, say it comes out to be $(x_1, y_1)$. Then we can compute the distance between these two points by applying the formula:

$$d = \sqrt{(x_0-x_1)^2 + (y_0-y_1)^2}$$